# 'TypeError' when using ColorProperty for Animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have an application which works with colors a lot. For ease of writing the program I have defined many of the color values as **ColorProperties** so that whenever the value changes the widgets adapt and I can use the observer-pattern on them.

In one part of my program I would like one of the widgets to start with a pre-defined color then be animated to the ColorProperties that I use, however, when doing so I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'kivy.properties.ColorProperty' object is not subscriptable
```

I would really prefer to use ColorProerties instead of tuples or lists holding the values and then re-writing the behavior of Properties for all of them. Is there a way that I can use ColorProperties for animations? My Code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App


class Custom(Button):
    
    def change_color(self):
        Animation(background_color=Example.fill_color).start(self)

class Example(App):
    fill_color = ColorProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
<Custom>:
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    on_release: root.change_color()
Custom:
    text: "Turn me into Red!!"
    font_size: 32
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place the `fill_color` class attribute on your 'Custom' `Button` class it works perfectly.

```
class Custom(Button):
    fill_color = ColorProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
    
    def change_color(self):
        Animation(background_color=self.fill_color).start(self)
```

If colors are shared then you could use classes as mixins:

```
class CustomMixin:
    fill_color = ColorProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
    
class Custom(CustomMixin, Button):    
    def change_color(self):
        Animation(background_color=self.fill_color).start(self)
```